# relational database: 2 queries as one

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a table name= wspollokator

```
-----------------
| user1 | user2  |
-----------------
|  1    |    3   |
-----------------
|  3    |    1   |
-----------------
|  7    |    0   |
-----------------
|  8    |    10  |
-----------------
|  9    |    0   |
-----------------
|  10   |    8   |
-----------------
```

I know how to display it like above:

```
SELECT p1.user1, p1.user2
FROM wspollokator p1
LEFT JOIN wspollokator p2 ON p1.user1 = p2.user2
WHERE p1.user1 <> p1.user2
```

but this is a relational table only with user ids

in another table name: zakwalifikowani
I have firstnames and lastnames of user1 and user2. The key is user1 user2

```
---------------------------------------------------
|firstname1 | lastname1  | firstname2 | lastname2 |
---------------------------------------------------
|  Tom      |  Hopkins   |   Mike     |  Ariston  |
---------------------------------------------------
|  Mike     |  Ariston   |   Tom      |  Hopkins  | 
---------------------------------------------------
|  Marlon   | Nickolson  |            |           |
---------------------------------------------------
|  John     | Nash       |   Jason    | Lin       |
---------------------------------------------------
|  Johny    | Bride      |            |           |
---------------------------------------------------
|  Jason    | Lin        |   John     | Nash      |
---------------------------------------------------
```

How can I use columns user1 and user2 to display it like above? I think that I need use query above because this query allow me to connect people into pairs

Comment: Please show the layouts of the tables.  Your first query doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "foreign key" in table  zakwalifikowani before you can join "user1=1" on "firstname1=Tom" (for example).

Comment: I have a foregin key. In zakwalifikowani I have a column user1

Comment: Q: What are "wspollokator" and "zakwalifikowani" actually supposed to be?  Google translate said "surgery" and "roomate" (?)

Comment: wspollokator is roomate zakwalifikowani people who get a double room bed ;)

Comment: These are Polish words. współlokator = roommate, zakwalifikowani = qualified, classified, scheduled [people].

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that your first query is really:

```
SELECT p1.user1, p1.user
FROM wspollokator p1
WHERE p1.user1 <> p1.user2;
```

The `left join` does nothing for the query.

To get names, you want two joins.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT w1.FirstName as FirstName1, w1.LastName as LastName1,
       w2.FirstName as FirstName2, w2.LastName as LastName2
FROM wspollokator p1 LEFT JOIN
     zakwalifikowani w1
     ON p1.user1 = w1.user LEFT JOIN
     zakwalifikowani w2
     ON p1.user2 = w2.user
WHERE p1.user1 <> p1.user2;
```